# Removing rows from a data frame having multiple entries in a column

Tags: r, dplyr

For each `CASE_ID` in my data there should be 1 `RF` and 1 `SJ` record

In pseudo code: for every CASE_ID,TIN and MPIN, count the number of TYPE for each TIN and MPIN combo and where the count is > 1 then remove the row with SJ

[image]

In my example above, since TIM SHORT has both an RF and SJ record I wish to remove the SJ record for him.

Here is the data frame above:

```
example_df <- data.frame(CASE_ID = c(123,123,123),TIN = c("BOB","TIM","TIM"),MPIN = c("LONG","SHORT","SHORT"),TYPE = c('SJ','RF','SJ'))
```

The final output should look as follows:

```
output <- data.frame(CASE_ID = c(123,123),TIN = c("BOB","TIM"),MPIN = c("LONG","SHORT"),TYPE = c('SJ','RF'))
```

I've tried to create a new help column using the following:

```
t <- example_df %>% group_by(CASE_ID,TIN,MPIN) %>% mutate(TYPE_COUNT = sum(TYPE == "RF" & TYPE == "SJ"))
```

But when I inspect the additional column TYPE_COUNT all rows are set to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean something like this:

```
example_df %>% group_by(TIN) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(take = ifelse(n == 1, 1, ifelse(n == 2 & TYPE == "RF", 1,  0))) %>% 
  filter(take == 1) %>% 
  select(-c(n, take))
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just want the count of types per group of CASE_ID,TIN,MPIN.You can try something like this,

`t <- example_df %>% group_by(CASE_ID,TIN,MPIN) %>% summarise(TYPE_COUNT = n_distinct(TYPE))`

Hope that works.